# Finding the Minimum Window in S which Contains All Elements from T

Tags: string, algorithm

I have a specific question about the code in the problem and its solution at http://articles.leetcode.com/finding-minimum-window-in-s-which

In the code below the figure (NOT the figure above the figure), 5th line of code from for loop

```cpp
if (hasFound[S[end]] <= needToFind[S[end]])  **// WHY this condition is required???**
    count++;
```

Based on my understanding

1) this if condition is not needed  and just (whenever found a char just increase count which represents the # of chars found so far)

```cpp
count++;
```

2) OR could be `<` (instead of `<=`) and equal doesn't seem to make sense for me

```cpp
if (hasFound[S[end]] < needToFind[S[end]])  
    count++;
```

I tested 1) and 2) but neither of them give me the correct answer for all cases.

only (`if` condition with `<=`) gives me the correct solution for all cases.

I really don't understand why

```cpp
if (hasFound[S[end]] <= needToFind[S[end]])
```

should be required to make this code work correctly for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that pattern T contains 3 chars A and 2 chars B.
So `needToFind['A'] = 3`
And you have to increment count, when `hasFound['A']` becomes 1, 2 and 3

When `hasFound['A']` becomes 2 only (you proposition about '<'), window contains only two A chars, it is impossible to make T, and count never reaches `tLen=5`

If remove this condition at all, 5 chars A give `count=5=tlen`, while window still doesn't contain any B

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand it completely.